# Getting talk page title using mediawiki API

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

Is there any way to fetch the talk page title of a given page title through MediaWiki API?

I know that I can get talkid using [prop=info](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Properties#info_.2F_in). But the problem is that there is no pageid for a talk page that does not exist yet. Also there are some obvious ways to get talk page title by adding a prefix to subject title, but it seems to me that they are all language/setup dependent...

Comment: Even if the wiki is in a different language, English can always be used. For example this URL will take you to the talk page of Stack Overflow on Hebrew Wikipedia even though Talk is called שיחה in Hebrew: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:StackOverflow

Comment: @Ainali Suppose the title is `תבנית:ש`. In some wikis it may be an article, in some others it may be a template, that is when the `תבנית:` part denotes the template namespace. In the former case I will need to prefix the title with `talk:`, in the latter case I will have to replace `תבנית:` with `template talk:`. The problem is that I don't know what is the appropriate prefix. Even if I get the namespace number using API, there may be some [custom namespaces](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Using_custom_namespaces) that use a user-defined prefix which I'm not aware of.

Comment: So, given a title, that might not exist, you want to know what the talk page would be **if** the page was created, in a wiki with custom namespaces that you do not know? Then I would just have grabbed the list of all namespaces from the API: http://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces, and looked my prefix up there. The talk page namespace will be in NS+1

Comment: @leo Thanks! I didn't know about `action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces`. That answers my question. If you repost this comment as an answer I would be glad to choose it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leo's answer: So, given a title, that might not exist, you want to know what the talk page would be if the page was created, in a wiki with custom namespaces that you do not know? Then I would just have grabbed the list of all namespaces from the API: http://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=namespaces, and looked my prefix up there. The talk page namespace will be in NS+1.

(Posted as community wiki so that this question isn't listed as unanswered.)